# Could $nT$ be covered by $mT$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

I understand that the torus of genus one, $T$, can be covered by three different spaces, each corresponding to a different subgroup of $\pi_1 (T) = \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$: the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$, $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$ and the torus $T$.

Obviously, the torus of genus $n$, $nT$, can be covered by one copy of itself. We could also argue that we could use multiple copies as a covering space, with the appropriate identifications over $n$ paths. However, using multiple copies doesn't really give us anything new, since the covering space would be $nT$ again.

I'm trying to find other covering spaces for $nT$ and, specifically, if some of those covering spaces could be $mT$ for some $m\neq n, \; n>1$.

The first thing that comes to mind is to exploit the bijection between covering spaces of $nT$ and subgroups of its fundamental group. However, since

$$
\pi_1 (nT) = \langle g_1,g_2, \dots, g_{2n} | g_1 g_2 g_1^{-1} g_2^{-1} \dots g_{2n-1} g_{2n} g_{2n-1}^{-1} g_{2n}^{-1} \rangle,
$$

I'm struggling to work with the subgroups of this group and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Let $\Sigma_g$ denotes the closed orientable surface of genus $g$. Suppose there is a $n$-fold covering $\Sigma_g\to \Sigma_h$. Then, $2-2g=\chi(\Sigma_g)=n\cdot \chi(\Sigma_h)=n\cdot (2-2h)$, i.e., $1-g=n-nh$, i.e., $g=nh+(1-n)$.

Comment: Conversely, if $g=nh+(1-n)$, then there are $n$ embedded simple closed curves that decomposes $\Sigma_g$ into $n$ copies of $\Sigma_{h-1,2}$: Think one hole(genus) in the middle and arrange other holes on $n$ distinct rays (each ray starts from the middle hole) so that each ray contains $(h-1)$ holes. Here, $\Sigma_{h-1,2}$ is the compact bordered subsurface of $\Sigma_g$ having genus $h-1$ and two boundary components.

Comment: Pasting two boundary components of $\Sigma_{h-1,2}$ suitably we have $\Sigma_h$, i.e., we have an $n$-fold cover from $\Sigma_g\to \Sigma_h$. The idea of this covering can be found in Allen Hatcher's Algebraic Topology book$(\text{Page }73)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I'll be checking the book you've recommended me as well.